# Why I obtain different visualization of the WordPress main menu when I run on local and remote?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am finding a very strange behavior with a WordPress main menu into this custom theme that use BootStrap: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

As you can see in the horizontal main menu the background of the voice related to the current page is red (ok, this is the right behavior)

The problem is that in the local version of the same website (use the same theme, I have uploaded it from my local web server to the previous onine web server) I have a different visualization of the menu (there is no the red brackground), here below I am attaching a picture of the local version:

[image]

This is the code that generate this main menu:

```
<!-- Header e barra di navigazione -->
        <header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default"" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(array(
                        'menu' => 'primary', 
                        'theme_location' => 'primary', 
                        'depth' => 2,
                        'container' => 'div', 
                        /*'container_class' => 'navbar navbar-default',*/
                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
                        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback', 
                        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
        </header><!-- /header -->
```

What could be the problem? the theme is the same

Tnx
Andrea

Comment: You've highlighted the `sample page` menu item in your screenshot, but you're on the Homepage on your local version....

Comment: ok...but in teory there is no difference...

Comment: @NickR Ok I have add the Homepage also to my local version and now it work well (I have the red background), maybe I am missing something...why if I have the Homepage as voice of my menu I have the red background for the selected voice but if I have not this voice I have not the red background? Tnx

Comment: Because you have this `CSS` rule - `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {    background-color: #990000; color: #FFFFFF;}` So every active/current page item will be highlighted in the `navigation menu`. If you're on the `Homepage`, then the `Homepage` item will be `highlighted`.